# How to upload to Cloudinary with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloudinary

I am new to Cloudinary. I want to upload images to Cloudinary in my web application using AngularJS but I don't know how. I can't find an fully example to use Cloudinary with Angularjs. I have tried to send $http
Please help me with my sample app to upload images to Cloudinary using unsigned_cloudinary_upload() and authenticated upload. I use Angular_File_upload at https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload in HTML template.
My sample app is on Plnkr at `[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xLHsznTtaQObwRmHgVL4?p=preview)`

Comment: In cloudinary document, they have direction for upload image from browser with jquery, maybe you can find the correct solution http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at Cloudinary's [official Angular.js library](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular), which also includes a fully working sample project.